# Nexmo API calls in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twilio, urlfetch, vonage

I have got SMS sending working within Google Sheets with Twilio using a slight modification to the code below (I have changed SMS payload fields and API key references)

The code is executing but I am just not getting the SMS, I tried digging into the logs in the dashboards on Nexmo platform but not error logs were showing.

Looks like a slight tweak needed on the authentication perhaps? Here are the API/payload sections where I think the error lies:

NEXMO

(WORKING CODE BELOW)

Can any Nexmo users spot an issue with the authentication that may fix this?

Comment: Usually failed authorization results in a 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden error

Comment: What do you expect adding things to `options` to do? `UrlFetchApp` does not take everything in the `params` argument and make them into a querystring and then append that to the given URL...  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params

Answer (score 1):

For the Nexmo SMS API, the credentials must be provided as `GET` parameters rather than via `Basic` auth. Your key should be in a parameter named `api_key` and secret in `api_secret`. See https://developer.nexmo.com/api/sms for more details on how the API works.

See also their guide on [Authorization](https://developer.nexmo.com/concepts/guides/authentication).

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Tried a few variants with no luck. Here is what I am currently working with edited in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code

```
  var payloads = {
    'to': mobileNumber,
    'text': smsMessage,
    'from': nexmoNumber,
    'api_key':api_key,
    'api_secret':api_secret
  };


  var messagesUrl = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' +api_key;
  var options = {
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'method':'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payloads)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl,options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```